# Using a defined constant inside a token

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have a list of functions:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_staticInit(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_gc(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_adjustExternalMemory(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint bytes);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_init(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_runScript(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring code, jstring name);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_callFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring name);
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_callFunctionD(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring name, jdouble d);
```

I'm trying to get rid of some duplication by using a `define`:

```
#define JNIFUNC JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity
JNIFUNC_staticInit(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz);
JNIFUNC_gc(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
JNIFUNC_adjustExternalMemory(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint bytes);
JNIFUNC_init(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
JNIFUNC_runScript(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring code, jstring name);
JNIFUNC_callFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring name);
JNIFUNC_callFunctionD(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jstring name, jdouble d);
```

However, this does not result in the desired output, presumably because `JNIFUNC_something` is not recognized as a reference to `JNIFUNC`.

Can I accomplish what I want?

Comment: Are you using c++ or c?

Comment: Look up _token pasting_. You'll need to define a function-style macro to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your preprocessor directive looks for the token `JNIFUNC`. The token `JNIFUNC_staticInit` is a completely different token even though it contains the same substring. You can put a space instead of an underscore for your functions like `JNIFUNC staticInit` which will make the preprocessor replace the token but the result would be `Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity staticInit` (note the space) which would most likely result in a syntax error.

The c++ solution is a namespace:

```
namespace Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity{
    void staticInit(...);
}
```

For c you could do something like this (also works in c++):

```
#define JNIFUNC(X) JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_##X
JNIFUNC(staticInit)(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz);
```

Comment: A namespace won't work unfortunately, since this exact function naming scheme is demanded by JNI. Making the function name an argument works though.

Answer (score 2):

The C preprocessor is a simple text replacement tool, but the text to replace must be a whole word (in the sense of a C symbol). Your macro `JNIFUNC` is not recognised when it is part of, say, `JNIFUNC_gc`.

You can use the token pasting syntax for macros, `##`, to create new symbols. In your case, you could define:

```
#define JNIFUNC(name) JNIEXPORT void \
    JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_##name 

JNIFUNC(staticInit)(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz);
JNIFUNC(gc)(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
JNIFUNC(adjustExternalMemory)(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint bytes);
```

Or, if you are willing to exploit the pattern of duplications even more, you could use variadic macro arguments to get rid of the first pair of parentheses:

```
#define JNIFUNC(name, ...) JNIEXPORT void \
    JNICALL Java_weber_droidtilla_DTActivity_##name(JNIEnv *env, \
    __VA_ARGS__)

JNIFUNC(staticInit, jclass clazz);
JNIFUNC(gc, jobject obj);
JNIFUNC(adjustExternalMemory, jobject obj, jint bytes);
```